# Sencha Touch Error...."has no method 'getId'"

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I am getting this error, in my browser console, after running "sencha app run native testing":

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getId'
```

When I look at the code in my browser I see this:

[image]

When I look at my own code for itemId of "foo3" I have this:

[image]

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Sencha cmd 5.1.1.39
Sencha touch 2.4.1
Running with cordova 4.2.0

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried setting your developer tools to pause on exceptions? It could be that there is different `item` that's causing this error. This will let you see which it is.

Comment: Why are using both id and itemId in your view config?

Comment: @jprofitt yes I have tried that. mindparse just for testing purposes, I took them away and I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried `item.id`?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon I have not, where would I add that in? thanks

Comment: Instead of `item.getId()` try `item.id`

Comment: @DawsonLoudon That's what I thought you meant, however everything in Ext.define ('Ext.ItemCollection', {..} is of the js library I am using, I didn't write the code. So I'm assuming it's something I am doing wrong, not them. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally rewrote the code so that I didn't have `var view = Ext.create('...`. instead I had `Ext.define('...` then I added:

```
 `var owningNavView = list.up('main'); 
  owningNavView.push({
  xtype : 'barFoo...'  });`
```

For sliding to the next card.

After that everything ran well with no errors.